# How do I align spans or divs horizontally?

Tags: css, html

My only problem is making them line up three-across and have equal spacing. Apparently, spans can not have width and divs (and spans with display:block) don't appear horizontally next to each other. Suggestions?

`<div style='width:30%; text-align:center; float:left; clear:both;'>` Is what I have now.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a table?

Comment: Because the data is not tabular.

Comment: The answers below are suitable, but consider that using a table will give you less of a headache if you end up making things more complicated. It's OK to use a table if it makes your work easier. Be pragmatic! :-)

Comment: seriously, don't use a table. This kind of thing is easy with CSS.

Comment: +1 on don't use a table. This is really easy. Being pragmatic about Tables As Layout is when you are having serious browser compatibility problems.

Comment: You already have the answer in your post. You should just not use clear:both; there! It is specifically to not allow the other divs in the same line. clear after them, so new stuff doesn't get in the same line.

Comment: "It's OK to use a table if it makes your work easier." is *absolutely terrible* advice. Please ignore! :)

Comment: You can check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9277311/621951

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use divs with the `float: left;` attribute which will make them appear horizontally next to each other, but then you may need to use clearing on the following elements to make sure they don't overlap.

Comment: Actually, you can just set `overflow: hidden`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323599/css-layouts-how-to-position-two-divs-horizontally-within-another-div/324553#324553

Comment: I find that this can break layout in subsequent divs. E.g., if I use your solution, and then try to `padding-left` in the div to the right, it gets ignored.

Comment: There's no reason to over-think: `<div style="display: in-line"></div><div style="display: in-line"></div>` should work fine.

Comment: using float introduce a whole bunch of new problems. `overflow: hidden` is the best solution.

Answer (score 40):

You can use

```
.floatybox {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 123px;
}
```

If you only need to support browsers that have support for inline blocks. Inline blocks can have width, but are inline, like button elements.

Oh, and you might wnat to add vertical-align: top on the elements to make sure things line up

Comment: vertical align does not work on block level elements. In this case we're talking about elements whose display has been set to inline-block.

Comment: inline-block is now [supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) in every [A grade browser](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tutorials/gbs/) except IE6/7, but there's a [hack](http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html) to get inline-block to work in IE6/7.

Answer (score 13):

#### My answer:

```
<style>
 #whatever div {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
  width: 30%;
}
</style>

<div id="whatever">
 <div>content</div>
 <div>content</div>
 <div>content</div>
</div>
```

#### Why?

Technically, a Span is an inline element, however it can have width, you just need to set their display property to block first. However, in this context, a div is probably more appropriate, as I'm guessing you want to fill these divs with content.

One thing you definitely don't want to do is have `clear:both` set on the divs. Setting it like that will mean that the browser will not allow any elements to sit on the same line as them. The result, your elements will stack up.

Note, the use of `display:inline`. This deals with the ie6 margin-doubling bug. You could tackle this in other ways if necessary, for example conditional stylesheets.

I've added a wrapper (#whatever) as I'm guessing these won't be the only elements on page, so you'll almost certainly need to segregate them from the other page elements.

Anyway, I hope that's helpful.

Comment: This didn't seem to work when I cut and paste it into jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry, typo there; I should have put a semi-colon after each of those lines, then it does work; I've edited accordingly. Although having reviewed this question again, I would suggest the OP needs to add a little more code to his example. As the answers here show, there a variety of approaches that can be used here and exactly what you use will depend on the context.

Answer (score 3):

you can do:

```
<div style="float: left;"></div>
```

or

```
<div style="display: inline;"></div>
```

Either one will cause the divs to tile horizontally.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it something like this as it gives you 3 even sized columns, even spacing and (even) scales. **Note:** This is not tested so it might need tweaking for older browsers.

```
<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    border:none;
}

.rightcontent {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    border:none
}

.hspacer {
    width:5%;
    float:left;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
</style>

<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="hspacer">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="hspacer">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="rightcontent">content</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```
<style>
.all {
display: table;
}
.maincontent {
float: left;
width: 60%; 
}
.sidebox { 
float: right;
width: 30%; 
}
<div class="all">
   <div class="maincontent">
       MainContent
   </div>
   <div class="sidebox"> 
       SideboxContent
   </div>
</div>
```

It's the first time I use this 'code tool' from overflow... but shoul do it by now...

Answer (score 1):

What you might like to do is look up CSS grid based layouts. This layout method involves specifying some CSS classes to align the page contents to a grid structure. It's more closely related to print-bsed layout than web-based, but it's a technique used on a lot of websites to layout the content into a structure without having to resort to tables.

Try this for [starters](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/04/14/designing-with-grid-based-approach/) from Smashing Magazine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the css Float property.  http://w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp

It works with block elements like div.  Alternatively, what are you trying to display, tables aren't evil if you're really trying to show a table of some information.

Comment: But it's not a table. They are just three things that I want to appear next to each other.

Comment: 404 page not found

Answer (score 0):

I would try to give them all `display: block;` attribute and using `float: left;`.

You can then set `width` and/or `height` as you like. You can even specify some vertical-alignment rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- CSS -->
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
.all { display: table; }
.menu { float: left; width: 30%; }
.content { margin-left: 35%; }
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="all">
<div class="menu">Menu</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

another...
try to use `float: left;` or `right;`, change the `width` for other values... it shoul work... also note that the 10% that arent used by the div its betwen them... sorry for bad english :)