# Aligning rounded corner boxes next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have created two rounded corner boxes which i would like to be aligned next to each other .But the 2nd box is appearing directly below the first one inspite of me using float:left on the 1st one. Any way to fix this would be really helpful. Below are the html and the css.

The HTML :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="containerDiv"> 

                    <!-- Box 1 -->

            <div id="box1" class="boxDiv">
                <div class="upperRound"></div>
                <div class="boxTagLine">
                        Some Tag Line
                </div>
                <div class="boxContent">
                    Heres some content
                </div>
                <div class="lowerRound"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Box 2 -->

            <div id="box2" class="boxDiv">
                <div class="upperRound"></div>
                <div class="boxTagLine">
                        Some Tag Line
                </div>
                <div class="boxContent">
                    Heres some content
                </div>
                <div class="lowerRound"></div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS :

```
#containerDiv {
    width: 1000px;

}
.boxDiv {
    width: 248px;
}
.upperRound {
    background-image: url('rounded_upper.gif');
    height: 20px;
}

.lowerRound {
    background-image: url('rounded_lower.gif');
    height: 20px;
}

.boxContent,.boxTagLine {
    border-left: 2px solid #B5B5B5;
    border-right: 2px solid #B5B5B5;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
    solid #B5B5B5;

}

.boxTagLine {
    color:#0066FF;
}

#box1 {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `-moz-border-radius` and other such options available in CSS for easily rounding corrners? They are available in most decent browsers (so no IE support)
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second div must float to right and next element should clear float. I'll add more info in a second.

---

I was a bit wrong. You even don't need clearing div.

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323599/css-layouts-how-to-position-two-divs-horizontally-within-another-div).

---

So - in your case, add this to css=>

```
#box2 {
    float:right;
}

#containerDiv {
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I didn't try it, but it should work.

---

Mine approach will leave space between boxes. So - it might be not desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using spans

But if you have to use divs :

```
.boxDiv {
    width: 248px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

float both boxes left:

```
#box1,#box2 {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off floating your .boxDiv left, like so:

```
.boxDiv {
    width: 248px;
    float: left;
}
```

That way if you add more boxes they'll float straight away, otherwise you'd have add the specific class names:

```
#box1, #box2, #box3, #box4 {
    float:left;
}
```