# How can I horizontally align my divs?

Tags: css

For some reason my divs won't center horizontally in a containing div:

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="block">Lorem</div>
  <div class="block">Ipsum</div>
  <div class="block">Dolor</div>
</div>
```

And sometimes there is a row div with just one block div in it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Very good link : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Answer (score 220, accepted):

To achieve what you are trying to do:

Consider using [`display: inline-block`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock) instead of `float`.

Answer (score 74):

Try this:

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; // center the content of the container
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block; // display inline with ability to provide width/height
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/wZB9z/)**

- having `margin: 0 auto;` along with `width: 100%` is useless because you element will take the full space.
- `float: left` will float the elements to the left, until there is no space left, thus they will go on a new line. Use `display: inline-block` to be able to display elements inline, but with the ability to provide size (as opposed to `display: inline` where width/height are ignored)

Comment: The demo is gone now

Answer (score 52):

Alignments in CSS had been a nightmare. Luckily, a new standard is introduced by W3C in 2009: [Flexible Box](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/). There is a good tutorial about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Personally I find it much more logical and easier to understand than other methods.

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.block {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="block">Lorem</div>
  <div class="block">Ipsum</div>
  <div class="block">Dolor</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly!

Answer (score 15):

Using FlexBox:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="block">Lorem</div>
  <div class="block">Ipsum</div>
  <div class="block">Dolor</div>
</div>

.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* for centering 3 blocks in the center */
  /* justify-content: space-between; for space in between */ 
}
.block {
  width: 100px;
}
```

The latest trend is to use Flex or CSS Grid instead of using Float. However, still some 1% browsers don't support Flex. But who really cares about old IE users anyway ;)

Fiddle: [Check Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ecolatur/wuwexsuw/)

Answer (score 10):

Another [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fNvgS/), using `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center`

**HTML**:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='btn'>Hello</div>
        <div class='btn'>World</div>
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container {
    ...
}
.row {
    text-align: center;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fNvgS/

Answer (score 8):

Although not covering this question (because you want to align the `<div>`s inside the container) but directly related: if you wanted to align just one div horizontally you could do this:

```
#MyDIV
{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If elements are to be displayed in one line and IE 6/7 do not matter, consider using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` instead of `float`.

`inline-block` leads to horizontal *gaps* between elements and requires zeroing that gaps. The most simple way is to set `font-size: 0` for parent element and then restore `font-size` for child elements that have `display: inline-block` by setting their `font-size` to a `px` or `rem` value.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the accepted answer, but eventually found that:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: anything less than 100%;
```

Works well so far.

Answer (score 3):

I've use this two approaches when I need to handle horizontal div alignment.
first ([Center Aligning Using the margin Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)):

```
.center-horizontal-align {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: (less than 100%) or in px
}
```

Setting the left and right margins to auto specifies that they should split the available margin equally. Center-aligning has no effect if the width is 100%.
and the second:

```
.center-horizontal-align {
    display: table
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Using the second approach is convenient when you have several elements and you want all of them to be centred in one table cell(i.e. several buttons in one cell).

Answer (score 1):

instead of float use flex

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```