# Aligning Div Blocks in a container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm currently designing a dashboard and I'm looking for a good/right way to align multiple divs in a container. I want the divs taking up maximum space left and right with the right margins .

[image]

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="1"></div>
    <div class="2"></div>
    <div class="3"></div>
    <div class="4"></div>
  </div>
</div>


.container {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [horizontally aligning divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277311/horizontally-aligning-divs)

Comment: I am not clear about your problem. Do you want to take more space by the blocks ?

Comment: Don't understand the downvote, the question is clearly not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `display` and the table-layout properties :
http://jsfiddle.net/3Q4qv/

```
.wrapper {
    border:solid;
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:15px;
/* give it width if you wish */
}
.container {
    display:table-row;
}
.container > div {
    display:table-cell;
    border:solid;
    /* let's give a min size since it is empty */
    height:2em;
    min-width:2em;
}
```

you can even make a mix with padding and border-spacing : http://jsfiddle.net/3Q4qv/1/

```
.wrapper {
    border:solid;
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank You. What's the advantage of using min-width?

Comment: none within a table unless you set `table-layout:` to `fixed;`, wich will not allow the cells to expand if `width` is specified :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Y3jS/3/ You should set a specific width on your `container` class, and then float each of the inner divs left.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1"><img style="width:50px; height: 50px; " src="http://www.mlahanas.de/Greeks/images/sq1.jpg"></img></div>
  <div class="box-2"><img style="width:50px; height: 50px; " src="http://www.mlahanas.de/Greeks/images/sq1.jpg"></img></div>
  <div class="box-3"><img style="width:50px; height: 50px; " src="http://www.mlahanas.de/Greeks/images/sq1.jpg"></img></div>
  <div class="box-4"><img style="width:50px; height: 50px; " src="http://www.mlahanas.de/Greeks/images/sq1.jpg"></img></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
}

.box-1, .box-2, .box-3, .box-4 {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
```

Comment: I can't add borders on the container in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/C2SGb/)**
Basically floating the blocks and letting their width be determined by a percentage of the parent (up to 25% since there are 4 - notice that I used only 23% and then I placed a 1% margin around all blocks giving you a 2% space between any two blocks -- adjust these numbers as you see fit).

```
.container {
    margin: 15px;
}
.box {
    float: left; 
    width: 23%; 
    margin: 0 1%;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="1 box"></div>
    <div class="2 box"></div>
    <div class="3 box"></div>
    <div class="4 box"></div>
</div>
```

*If you don't want space between the boxes, this approach really shines - use `width:25%;  margin: 0;`*

**Alternatively, you could use** `display: inline-block;`

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="1 box"></div><!--
    --><div class="2 box"></div><!--
    --><div class="3 box"></div><!--
    --><div class="4 box"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%; 
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this perspective, never really thought of this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use any width in your container like:

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
}
```

Then you can set the style for all elements inside. Look that if you want to add border at the elements, try to use the [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) property.

```
.box {
    width: 21%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2%;
}
```