# Three centered boxes next to each other html

Tags: html, css

On my site, I have a line of boxes which are divs going down the center of the page. I would like to put 4 of them next to each other in a horizontal line, and when the page resizes it will go down to 3 next to each other, then two, then one.

I am going to resize the boxes, so they will fit in.

The site is [here](http://001a.com) 
You can use page source to find code and the css can be found [here](http://001a.com/style.css)

Thank you!

Comment: You should ( Strongly advise you to ) post the html / css here.. It's kinda rude making us browse `n` links to find your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [horizontally aligning divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277311/horizontally-aligning-divs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(or you can more easily adjust the width of the screen here: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/359/)

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.container  {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align: center;` on the container, `display: inline-block;` on the boxes and maybe set a minimum width on the container as well.