# Get 2div boxes in left and right corner

Tags: html, css

I want to have two div boxes one at left and another at right corner.

With the help off following code it comes but both are not in same align.
It comes one after another.
Here is my code

```
<style>
            html { margin:0; padding:0; font-size:62.5%; }
            body { max-width:300px; font-size:14px; font-size:1.4em; }
            h1 { font-size:1.8em; }
            .demo { overflow:auto; border:1px solid silver; min-height:100px;min-width: 200px;float: left }
            .demo1 { overflow:auto; border:1px solid silver; min-height:100px;min-width: 200px; float: right}
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.min.css" />
    </head>

    <body><div id="frmt" class="demo"></div>
        <div id="frmt1" class="demo1"></div>
        </body>
```

So it comes like
[image]

and I want it to look like
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [horizontally aligning divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277311/horizontally-aligning-divs)

Comment: You have set max-width of body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of `max-width: 300px;` in you `body`. Removing that would do the trick.

`demo` and `demo1` are having a `min-width` of 200px each, summing to 400px. But the `body` have a `max-width` of only 300px.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    html {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 62.5%;
    }
    body {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-size: 1.4em;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.8em;
    }
    .demo {
      overflow: auto;
      border: 1px solid silver;
      min-height: 100px;
      min-width: 200px;
      float: left
    }
    .demo1 {
      overflow: auto;
      border: 1px solid silver;
      min-height: 100px;
      min-width: 200px;
      float: right
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="frmt" class="demo"></div>
  <div id="frmt1" class="demo1"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex is becoming more and more common place and means you don't have to have your boxes so far apart

```css
.demo-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.demo {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.demo-button {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-container">
  <div id="frmt" class="demo"></div>
  <button class="demo-button">>></button>
  <div id="frmt1" class="demo"></div>
</div>
```

I know your question had already been answered, but there is always more than one way to solve a problem :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
     <body><div id="frmt" class="demo" style="float:left;"></div>
    <div id="frmt1" class="demo1" style="float:right;"></div>
    </body>
```