# How can I get there three elements to align horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a row with html and css which displays two images on the left and right side of the browser and text in the middle of these two images. I am attempting to have them all lie horizontally aligned with inlay. Here is the relevant code:

```
<div class="col" id="egg_area">
      <img id="egg_img" src="img/egg.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" id="introduction">
      <p>Hello! Welcome to the Bacon, Egg, and Cheese Sandwich Web    Map! The map below will allow you to search for the best deals on your favorite breakfast sandwich! Simply click a location anywhere within the 5 boroughs to reveal its nearest delis. By clicking each of the revealed markers you can view more details about each specific deli.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="bacon_area">
      <img id="bacon_img" src="img/bacon.png"></img>
    </div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#egg_area {
position: absolute;
display: inline;
}

#egg_img {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
display: inline;
}

#intro_area {
height: 500px;
font-size: large;
display: inline;
}

#title {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
color: white;
text-decoration: underline;
width: 250px;
margin-top: 50px;

}

#introduction {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 55px;
width: 100px;
color: white;
margin-top: -9px;
display: inline;
}

#bacon_area {
position: absolute;
display: inline;
}

#bacon_img {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
display: inline;
}
```

The first image seems to align with the centered text, but the second image overflows into a new row. I've tried changing image sizes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I will recommend you use css grid or flex, that will give you a lot of flexibility. If you need help with that let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [horizontally aligning divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277311/horizontally-aligning-divs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap you contents within a div and apply css `display: flex` to align them horizontally

CSS

```
#egg_img {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
}

#title {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
color: white;
text-decoration: underline;
width: 250px;
margin-top: 50px;

}

#introduction {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 55px;
width: 100px;
color: black;
margin-top: -9px;
}


#bacon_img {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="display:flex">
    <div class="col" id="egg_area">
      <img id="egg_img" src="img/egg.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" id="introduction">
      <p>Hello! Welcome to the Bacon, Egg, and Cheese Sandwich Web    Map! The map below will allow you to search for the best deals on your favorite breakfast sandwich! Simply click a location anywhere within the 5 boroughs to reveal its nearest delis. By clicking each of the revealed markers you can view more details about each specific deli.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="bacon_area">
      <img id="bacon_img" src="img/bacon.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/23tbestw/)

Comment: Thank you. I went with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bigCol {
  background: cyan;
  width: 60%;  
  flex-shrink: 0;

  /* Just set the size for the bigger column and set flex-shrink to 0, meaning it will never have
     a smaller width. */
     
  transition: width ease-out .5s;
}

.bigCol:hover {
  width: 20%;
}

.smallCol {
  background: red;
  /* width: 20%; */
  
  /* No width needed here, they will take the rest of the space, although you could add it anyway
     to make sure both small columns take the same width, regardless of the dimension of their
     content, which could be different. */
}

.smallCol,
.bigCol {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* This will vertically center the content of all the columns. */
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  margin: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="smallCol">
    <img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/x6q2SEFflggiQ/giphy.gif?response_id=592190da053fdebcd421e31e"></img>
  </div>

  <div class="bigCol">
    <p>Do you see something weird in the pictures? Hover to resize the columns!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="smallCol">
    <img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/x6q2SEFflggiQ/giphy.gif?response_id=592190da053fdebcd421e31e"></img>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to have horizontally aligned content is to use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`

```
<div class="display-table">
    <div class="col" id="egg_area">
        <img id="egg_img" src="img/egg.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" id="introduction">
        <p>Hello! Welcome to the Bacon, Egg, and Cheese Sandwich Web Map! 
         The map below will allow you to search for the best
         deals on your favorite breakfast sandwich! Simply click a 
         location anywhere within the 5 boroughs to reveal its
         nearest delis. By clicking each of the revealed markers 
         you can view more details about each specific deli.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="bacon_area">
        <img id="bacon_img" src="img/bacon.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.display-table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.display-table div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Be aware that for this to work you need to remove `display:inline` from your `#id` css rules since they would have higher specificity and override the `display: table-cell`.