# Css left and right float for divs

Tags: html, css

I need  to divide my div to left and right column. So div with rightColumnRow must be in right column, with leftColumnRow - in left column.

```css
.leftColumnRow {
     float: left;
     width: 50%;
     background-color: #CCF;
}
.rightColumnRow {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #FFA;
}
```

```html
<div class="projectTabContent">
    <div class="rightColumnRow row  ">
        rightColumnRow
    </div>
    <div class="leftColumnRow row  ">
        leftColumnRow
    </div>
    <div class="leftColumnRow row  ">
        leftColumnRow
    </div>
    <div class="leftColumnRow row  ">
        leftColumnRow
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumnRow row  ">
        rightColumnRow
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work correctly. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: don't need to use float anymore :) use `display: inline-block`

Comment: what is css class: row  ?

Comment: why not simply text-align inside the div ?

Comment: What do you need, can you maybe add a mockup of your expected result.

Comment: https://clip2net.com/s/3Sppx5x
And div order can be different, but div with rightColumnRow must be in right column, with leftColumnRow - in left column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I horizontally align my divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277311/how-can-i-horizontally-align-my-divs)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs You don't need inline-block anymore. Use Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

```css
.leftColumnRow {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #CCF;
}
.rightColumnRow {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #FFA;
}
```

```html
<div class="projectTabContent">
    <div class="rightColumnRow row  ">
        <div class="row  ">
            rightColumnRow
        </div>
        <div class=" row  ">
            rightColumnRow
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="leftColumnRow row  ">
        <div class="row  ">
            leftColumnRow
        </div>
        <div class="row  ">
            leftColumnRow
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```