# Need help trying to convert radio buttons into a row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert these radio buttons from a column into a row but I cannot seem to achieve this outcome. Would someone be kind enough to help me out. I have been trying to do this for hours with no success. The issue seems to be in the SCSS but im cannot figure it out.

## **HTML for the radio buttons**

```
<div class="x">
  <div class="radiobtn">
    <input type="radio" id="huey"
      name="drone" value="huey" checked />
    <label for="huey">Word</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radiobtn">
    <input type="radio" id="dewey"
      name="drone" value="dewey" />
    <label for="dewey">Powerpoint</label>
  </div>
              
  <div class="radiobtn">
    <input type="radio" id="louie"
      name="drone" value="louie" />
    <label for="louie">Speech</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radiobtn">
    <input type="radio" id="suey"
      name="drone" value="suey" />
    <label for="suey">Youtube</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

## **SCSS for the radio buttons**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap');

$accentcolor: #fcae2c;
$lightcolor: #fff;
$darkcolor: rgb(110, 110, 110);

.x {
    max-width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.radiobtn {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    label {
        display: block;
        background: lighten($accentcolor, 30%);
        color: $darkcolor;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: 2px solid lighten($accentcolor, 20%);
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400px;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        &:after,
        &:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            right: 11px;
            top: 11px;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            background: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
        }
        &:before {
            background: transparent;
            transition: 0.1s width cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1) 0s,
                0.3s height cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 2) 0.1s;
            z-index: 2;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 13px;
            background-position: center;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNS4zIDEzLjIiPiAgPHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIgZD0iTTE0LjcuOGwtLjQtLjRhMS43IDEuNyAwIDAgMC0yLjMuMUw1LjIgOC4yIDMgNi40YTEuNyAxLjcgMCAwIDAtMi4zLjFMLjQgN2ExLjcgMS43IDAgMCAwIC4xIDIuM2wzLjggMy41YTEuNyAxLjcgMCAwIDAgMi40LS4xTDE1IDMuMWExLjcgMS43IDAgMCAwLS4yLTIuM3oiIGRhdGEtbmFtZT0iUGZhZCA0Ii8+PC9zdmc+);
        }
    }
    input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        appearance: none;
        &:checked + label {
            background: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
            animation-name: blink;
            animation-duration: 1s;
            border-color: $accentcolor;
            &:after {
                background: $accentcolor;
            }
            &:before {
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
            }
        }
    }
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
    }
    10% {
        background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
    }
    11% {
        background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 20%);
    }
    29% {
        background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 20%);
    }
    30% {
        background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
    }
    50% {
        background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 20%);
    }
    45% {
        background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
    }
    50% {
        background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 20%);
    }
    100% {
        background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I horizontally align my divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277311/how-can-i-horizontally-align-my-divs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .radiobtn{} adding display: inline-block; will get the result I believe you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you brendan this has solved my issue! Really appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use 'Display: Inline' instead of 'Display: Block;' in .radiobtn class**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap');
$accentcolor: #fcae2c;
$lightcolor: #fff;
$darkcolor: rgb(110,
110,
110);
.x {
  max-width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.radiobtn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  label {
    display: block;
    background: lighten($accentcolor, 30%);
    color: $darkcolor;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 2px solid lighten($accentcolor, 20%);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:after,
    &:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      right: 11px;
      top: 11px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
    }
    &:before {
      background: transparent;
      transition: 0.1s width cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1) 0s, 0.3s height cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 2) 0.1s;
      z-index: 2;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 13px;
      background-position: center;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNS4zIDEzLjIiPiAgPHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIgZD0iTTE0LjcuOGwtLjQtLjRhMS43IDEuNyAwIDAgMC0yLjMuMUw1LjIgOC4yIDMgNi40YTEuNyAxLjcgMCAwIDAtMi4zLjFMLjQgN2ExLjcgMS43IDAgMCAwIC4xIDIuM2wzLjggMy41YTEuNyAxLjcgMCAwIDAgMi40LS4xTDE1IDMuMWExLjcgMS43IDAgMCAwLS4yLTIuM3oiIGRhdGEtbmFtZT0iUGZhZCA0Ii8+PC9zdmc+);
    }
  }
  input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    appearance: none;
    &:checked+label {
      background: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
      animation-name: blink;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      border-color: $accentcolor;
      &:after {
        background: $accentcolor;
      }
      &:before {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
      }
    }
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
  }
  10% {
    background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
  }
  11% {
    background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 20%);
  }
  29% {
    background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 20%);
  }
  30% {
    background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 20%);
  }
  45% {
    background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 20%);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: lighten($accentcolor, 15%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div class="radiobtn">
    <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked />
    <label for="huey">Word</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radiobtn">
    <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey" />
    <label for="dewey">Powerpoint</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radiobtn">
    <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie" />
    <label for="louie">Speech</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radiobtn">
    <input type="radio" id="suey" name="drone" value="suey" />
    <label for="suey">Youtube</label>
  </div>
</div>
```