# HTML. Columns in a single line

Tags: html, css

How to build a column in a row?

Now the columns are vertically one after the other.

example:

█

█

█

But I need to build them horizontally.

█
█
█

This is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/52u4W/) to the source code.

Comment: I found several questions that deal with the same on SO, have you gone through those????

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to you to wrap them to some outer `<div>` and set `float: left` property for `<div>`.

Here is basic example how to do it.

`​HTML` code:

```
<div class="column"​​​​​​​​​>
   <span>Simply dummy text</span>
</div>

<div class="column">
   <span>Simply dummy text</span>
</div>

<div class="column">
   <span>Simply dummy text</span>
</div>
```

And `CSS`:

```
.column {
   width: 160px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 5px;
   text-align: center;
}​
```

**Note:** Here is working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGbvN/2/).

**Note 2:** Also if you want to use this `class` so just only for `<div>` element, declare it as `div.column`.
​

**Updated:**
Thanks to **@poncha** for suggestion. Answer updated.

Comment: The id being used is not unique. Would it make more sense to use a class here?

Comment: class should be used here. id [MUST be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id)

Answer (score 1):

Several possible solutions.

1) Use `float: left` on each of your s which you need to line up on the same row. Optionally, add width to each of those to avoid cluttered content. Include all of the <div>s in a parent container

2) Tile up each of the s horizontally using `display: inline`

3) Actually this is copied from  an earlier SO answers, I've used it many-a-times...

```
<style>
 #whatever div {
  display: inline
  margin: 0 1em 0 1em
  width: 30%
}
</style>

<div id="whatever">
 <div>content</div>
 <div>content</div>
 <div>content</div>
</div>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/226261/608170

Answer (score 1):

semantically seems to me more like a list. do you actually have to take care about IE7? if not I suggest you render a markup like

```
<ul class="inline-list">
  <li>my content</li>
  <li>my content</li>
  <li>my content</li>
</ul>
```

and then use via CSS

```
.inline-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALNTA/)

the list entries behave like block elements then (like a simple div for example) so you can apply width and height and so on... nice about that is that it will automatically do line breaks. (which would not be that easy for floating imho)

for IE7: graceful degradation if displayed as block elements but depends on the use case (maybe you can solve this by using display: inline; but I can not prove this right now)

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left to div & fixed width with overflow:hidden property

```
div { 
    -webkit-column-width: 300px;
    -webkit-column-height: 300px;    
    height: 300px;
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    -webkit-column-gap:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/52u4W/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div>
        <div id="one" class="clhr">
             <h3>Column1</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="two" class="clhr" >
             <h3>Column2</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="three" class="clhr">
             <h3>Column3</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
   .clhr {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    width: 200px;
}
```